# Trouble reversing a string in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I am trying to reverse a string in assembly.
However my code does not seem to work correctly.
I added a newline string for better readability.

I am using linux and nasm as compiler.

I thought that if I took the values of the adresspointers and switched them at the correct place, the string would eventually be reversed and then get back to normal.

This is my code:

```
section .data
    hello     db 'Hello world!'
    helloLen  equ $-hello
    derp db '=========',10
    derplen equ $-derp

section .text
    global main

main:
    mov eax,0
    mov ecx,helloLen

    reverse:
        ;move pointer
        mov ebx,hello
        add ebx,eax
        push eax

        ;move pointer
        mov eax,hello
        add eax,ecx
        push ecx

        ;switch bytes
        push ebx
        mov ebx,[ebx]
        mov [eax],ebx
        pop ebx
        mov eax,[eax]
        mov [ebx],eax

        ;print text
        mov eax,4
        mov ebx,1
        mov ecx,hello
        mov edx,helloLen
        int 80h

        ;Print newline
        mov eax,4
        mov ebx,1
        mov ecx,derp
        mov edx,derplen
        int 80h

        ;increment and decrement
        pop ecx
        dec ecx
        pop eax
        inc eax

        cmp eax,helloLen
    jne reverse

    end:
        mov eax,1
        mov ebx,0
        int 80h
```

This is the output I get:

```
Hello world!Hell=====
Hello worldellol=====
Hello worlllo ol=====
Hello worlo w ol=====
Hello woo wow ol=====
Hello wooooow ol=====
Hello wooooow ol=====
Helloooooooow ol=====
Helloooooooow ol=====
Helooowooooow ol=====
Heoow wooooow ol=====
How o wooooow ol=====
```

Comment: There are a few things I notice right off the bat:  
1) When you swap characters, you should be swapping bytes, not dwords.
2) ecx should start at helloLen-1.
3) The termination condition for the algorithm is wrong; you'll end up swapping each character twice.  (Stop when eax >= ecx)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way to reverse a string by swapping characters is to swap the first and last, then the second and next to last, etc. In C, you would write:

```
for (i = 0; i < len/2; ++i)
{
    c = s[i];
    s[i] = s[len-i-1];
    s[len-i-1] = c;
}
```

In assembly language, the easiest way is to set up the ESI and EDI registers to point to the start and end of the string, then loop. At each iteration, you increment ESI and decrement EDI. The result looks something like this:

```
mov ecx, helloLen
mov eax, hello
mov esi, eax  ; esi points to start of string
add eax, ecx
mov edi, eax
dec edi       ; edi points to end of string
shr ecx, 1    ; ecx is count (length/2)
jz done       ; if string is 0 or 1 characters long, done
reverseLoop:
mov al, [esi] ; load characters
mov bl, [edi]
mov [esi], bl ; and swap
mov [edi], al
inc esi       ; adjust pointers
dec edi
dec ecx       ; and loop
jnz reverseLoop
```

Comment: @gandolf: Yes. Because when the length is odd the middle character does not move. For example, when length is 3 only one iteration of the loop is performed, swapping items 0 and 2. The item in the middle does not move.

Comment: You don't need a separate counter or length calculation, just `cmp esi, edi` / `jb` as the loop condition, like `do{}while(++p_start < --p_end);` is the idiomatic way to reverse in-place.

Answer (score 0):

When I did this for an interview, I came up with this...  It is a bit Microsoft specific, but it's roughly the same as what @Jim Mischel wrote, except this calculates the length of the string rather than being passed it etc.

This function is naked, so since there's no prolog or epilog you do have to be careful about what registers you can use.  (Unless you push and pop if you use them.  In this example, I'm not using any registers that need to be preserved)

```
#define USE_STRLEN 0                                    ; Use strlen to find string length?

__declspec(naked) uint8_t* string_rev(uint8_t* s)
{
    __asm
    {
              mov    eax, dword ptr[esp + 4]            ; Get the address of string
              test   eax, eax                           ; Been passed a null pointer?
              jz     lp_3
#if (USE_STRLEN)
              push   eax                                ; Push string address onto stack
              call   strlen
              pop    ecx                                ; Pop our string back off the stack
              xchg   ecx, eax                           ; String length in eax
#else
              or     ecx, 0ffffffffh                    ; Start ecx at -1
        lp_1:
              inc    ecx
              test   byte ptr[eax + ecx], 0ffh          ; Test string byte for zero
              jnz    lp_1                               ; ecx = string length

#endif
              lea    edx, dword ptr[eax + ecx - 1]      ; edx = last character in string
              and    ecx, -2                            ; Is string 1 character or less?
              jz     lp_3
        lp_2:
              mov    cl, byte ptr[edx]
              mov    ch, byte ptr[eax]
              mov    byte ptr[eax], cl
              mov    byte ptr[edx], ch
              inc    eax
              dec    edx
              cmp    edx, eax                           ; Loop whilst one pointer is less
              ja     lp_2                               ; than the other (equiv. len/2)
        lp_3:
              ret                                       ; Reversed string in eax
    }
}
```