# Reverse a string using the stack

Tags: assembly

I'm using dosbox and this is an assignment. I have to reverse the string using the stack. My thinking was to push the string one character at a time onto the stack then pop out into RevString one by one. I can't figure out how to actually do this though. Here is what I have so far.

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100h

.DATA

String      DB  "NAJAFI", 13, 10, "$"
RevString   DB  6 DUP(?), '.', 13, 10, "$"

.CODE

Main PROC

    ;; Set up ds register to point to the data
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    ;; printing a string in dos
    mov dx, OFFSET String
    mov ah, 9h
    int 21h

    ;; reverse the string by using the stack
    mov ax, WORD PTR String
    push ax
    pop ax
    ;mov RevString, ax


    ;; print the reverse string in dos
    mov dx, RevString
    mov ah, 9h
    int 21h

    ;; DOS return
    mov al, 0
    mov ah, 4ch
    int 21h

Main ENDP
END Main
```

Comment: Hint: You need a loop.

Comment: I'm alright with manually choosing the index, therefore I wouldn't need a loop correct? If so what is the syntax for actually pushing say the letter "N" to the stack?

Comment: You need a loop.  If you do it any other way you will bind your code to a specific string length, and get a bad grade. :)

Comment: I know that it will then have a dependency on that specific string but this assignment isn't graded on good conventions ha just implementation using a stack.

Comment: In any case though, I'm still trying to figure out how to actually push a character to the stack. That's mostly where I need help I believe.

Comment: To get the first character: mov al,BYTE PTR String / push ax

Comment: There's some more hints here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13587313/trouble-reversing-a-string-in-assembly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To push a string onto the stack:

```
    mov di, offset String
    mov cx, string_length
    xor ax, ax
pushloop:
    mov al, [di]
    push ax
    inc di
    dec cx
    jnz pushloop
```

You can do the same type of thing to pop the characters from the stack into `RevString`.

Comment: Thank you for showing me how to do that loop. Would you care to show how to pop back from the stack in a similar loop?

Comment: @user45763: Popping it back is very similar: pop from the stack, store the character. Loop until done.

Answer (score 0):

For 80x86, the stack is aligned on a 2-byte, 4-byte or 8-byte boundary (2-byte alignment for 16-bit). If you push a byte the CPU will automatically add padding to ensure alignment.

To get around that you can push words instead. For example:

```
lodsw      ;ax = next pair of bytes
rol ax,8   ;Swap the bytes
push ax    ;Store the bytes
```

The problem with this is that detecting and handling "end of string" becomes messy, as (in your case) the `$` character could end up in `AL` or `AH` (depending on whether the string has an odd or even number of characters).

Of course there's several alternatives. The first would be to store the reversed string on the stack with padding, then copy it somewhere else while removing the padding.

Another alternative would be to reserve enough space on the stack (e.g. subtract a value from `SP`) and then create the reversed string in the space you reserved by using normal `MOV` instructions (without using `PUSH`).

Answer (score 0):

Your string handling is also too complicated if you're not sure whats going on

Create a bounded data block to make things easy and dynamic

```
.start
db  "NAJAFI"
.end

mov edx,end-start ;a nice and simple string length
mov ebx,start     ;a nice and simple string start point
mov ecx,0

.loadstack
mov eax,[ebx]
push eax
inc ecx
cmp ecx,edx
jz printsetup
inc ebx
jmp loadstack

.printsetup
mov ecx,0

.printstackbackwards
pop eax
[PRINT IT OUT BIT]
inc ecx
cmp ecx,edx
jnz printstackbackwards

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I wanted to give it a try, here is my version. I'm thinking if this can be optimized though.

```
;**********************************************
;
; Reverse a string using the stack.
; EAX is the pointer to the C string.
ReverseWithStack proc


    mov esi, eax
    mov edi, eax

_push_loop:
    mov al, [esi]
    cmp al, 0
    jz _pop_loop

    push ax
    inc esi
    jmp _push_loop

_pop_loop:
    mov al, [edi]
    cmp al, 0
    jz _done

    pop ax
    mov [edi], al
    inc edi
    jmp _push_loop

_done:

    ret

ReverseWithStack ENDP
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you cannot push bytes on stack, only words and double words.
Here's an idea:
you have the string,
calculate the string length using a procedure,
push the string on the stack,
add the string length-1 to EBP (that is, if directly above EBP u have the string otherwise manipulate it accordingly),
This will now point to the end of the string. Now you can use EBP to get the last character, then decrement by one and continue getting character by character.

Answer (score -2):

You don't reverse the string, the stack does it for you

String      DB  "NAJAFI"

is pushed on like:

I <---first pop

F

A

J

A

N <--First push: stack pointer+2(or4)

So when you pop it you simply pop straight to a print function and it's reversed.

Magic !