# How to reverse of each word in a string in nasm?

Tags: string, assembly, nasm, reverse

I have to write a program which reads a string of 25 characters and returns the same string the letters of each word reversed in asm language

For example:

```
Input >> Hello world. How are you?
Output >> olleH .dlrow woH era ?uoy
```

This is what I've done:

```
%include "asm_io.inc"
segment .data

prompt1 db    "Insert the strin: ", 0       ; don't forget nul terminator
prompt2 db    "The string is: ", 0
prompt3 db    "The reverse string is: ", 0

segment .bss

vector  resb 25
vectorInvert resb 25   
aux resb 1 
aux2 resb 1                                          

segment .text
        global  asm_main
asm_main:


        mov     eax, prompt1      ; print out prompt
            call    print_string


        mov edi, vector ;vetor e do tipo byte
        mov ecx, 25
        read:
            call read_char  
            stosb       
        loop read

        mov eax, 0
        mov edx, 0
        mov esi, vector
        mov ecx, 25
        stack:
            mov al, [esi]
            cmp al, " "
            jz stack2
            movzx eax, al
            push eax
            add eax, 1  
            add esi, 1
        loop stack

        stack2:
            mov [aux], ecx
            mov [aux2], eax         
            mov ecx, 25
            sub ecx, eax
            mov edi, vectorInvert           
            lp:
                pop eax
                add edx, 1
                mov [edi], eax
                add edi, 1
            loop lp
            add eax, 1
            add edx, 1
            add esi, 1
            add edi, 1
            mov ecx, [aux]
            mov eax, [aux2]
            cmp eax, 25
            jz out
            jnz stack


        out:

            mov     eax, prompt3
            call    print_string

            mov edi, vectorInvert
            mov ecx, 25
            print:
                lodsb
                call print_char 
            loop print
            call print_nl

            leave                     
            ret
```

I'm stuck in there, I have no idea how to keep going. I would really appreciate some help with this code.
I am using the library from here: drpaulcarter.com/pcasm/linux-ex.zip
(Please note that I'm a totally newbie in assembly.)

Comment: what processor is this?

Comment: the processor is Intel

Comment: I am using the library from here: http://www.drpaulcarter.com/pcasm/linux-ex.zip

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trouble reversing a string in assembly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13587313/trouble-reversing-a-string-in-assembly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... I see some minor issues with the code as posted. Besides spelling "strin" rong, the variables `aux` and `aux2` are too small. If you're going to put a 32-bit register in 'em, they need to be 32 bits - 4 bytes - `resd 1` or `resb 4` (either would work). I think you may not need these variables, but make 'em the right size.

Then, if you're going to use `leave` at the end of `asm_main`, you need to start with `enter 0, 0`. I think all of Dr. Carter's examples do this.

Your input routine looks like it would work, but forces the user to enter 25 characters exactly, even if they have a shorter "strin" in mind. This has the advantage that you know how many characters you've got, but isn't very flexible. Dr. Carter's library provides a `read_string` which returns a zero-terminated string. We could do a `stringlen` on this, but since we're going to have to examine each character anyway, we could just watch for the zero.

Then you seem to be doing pretty well up through the `push eax`. Then you `add eax, 1`. Huh? It looks like you intend `eax` to be both the character and a counter. This isn't going to work!

I had in mind pushing each character, counting it, and then examining what it was. This would make "Hello " into " olleH" (when we `pop` 'em). Not too bad, but it causes a problem when we get to the end (if we're using a zero-terminated string). I decided to examine the characters first, pushing (and counting) only the non-space (and non-zero) characters...

```
mov esi, string
mov edi, reverse

nextword:
xor ecx, ecx ; counter - per word
pushloop:
lodsb
cmp al, ' '
jz poploop
cmp al, 0
jz cleanuploop
push eax ; if not, save it (plus garbage)
inc ecx
jmp pushloop

poploop:
pop eax ; including garbage
stosb ; store al only, ignoring garbage
loop poploop
mov al, ' '
stosb
jmp nextword

cleanuploop:
pop eax
stosb
loop cleanuploop
mov al, 0 ; zero-terminate our string for "print_string"
stosb
```

This "works". Do you see the flaw? If the pesky user enters a space as the first character (or last, or enters nothing) we wind up in `poploop` (etc.) with `ecx` already zero. The `loop` instruction decrements `ecx` and jumps if non-zero. If `ecx` is already zero, it decrements to 0FFFFFFFFh. This loops a lot of times. Crash in flames!

I solved it like this...

```
mov esi, string
mov edi, reverse

nextword:
xor ecx, ecx
pushloop:
lodsb
cmp al, ' '
jz poploop
cmp al, 0
jz cleanuploop
push eax
inc ecx
jmp pushloop

poploop:
jecxz skippop ; bail out if ecx is zero
pop eax
stosb
loop poploop
skippop:
mov al, ' '
stosb
jmp nextword

cleanuploop:
jecxz skippop2
pop eax
stosb
loop cleanuploop
skippop2:
mov al, 0
stosb
```

Display it, and exit cleanly, of course. Looks better if you put a newline after.

You do `movzx eax, al` before pushing `eax`. Doesn't hurt, but we could `push eax` whatever's in the upper bytes. Just ignore everything but `al` after popping it. You can't just `push al`, as you know...

I hope this isn't too much like "doing it for you" - I couldn't think of a better way to explain it. There are different ways to do it. Hope this will give you some ideas how to proceed.

Edit: well they won't let me add a comment(?). Try this instead:
`enter 0, 0` does the same as `push ebp` / `mov ebp, esp`. If the first parameter were non-zero, it would subtract that amount from `esp` - to make space for local variables. `leave` does the same as `mov esp, ebp` / `pop ebp`. Prolog and epilog for your `asm_main` function called from `driver.c`. Go by `skel.asm` in the examples.

Answer (score 1):

Reversing a string using the stack:

1. Copy the stackpointer
2. Push a 0 Byte (or '$' if using DOS)
3. Push each character of the string
4. Take the stackpointer as the strings address
5. Print it (or copy it or whatever should be done with it).
6. Restore the stackpointer

Things which may have to be taken care of: If the stackpointer becomes odd, it might cause a problem so in that case, an additional 0 byte may be pushed first to keep the stack aligned.

Comment: You can't push a single byte.  `push r16` is available in all modes (including 64bit), so you could load a word and swap it (with `rol ax, 8`) before pushing.  Or unroll your load-and-check loop to build up 2 or 4B in a register with shifts, so you can `push` that.  Or don't use an actual `push` instruction at all.  Adjusting the stack pointer downward one way or another as you go is a good suggestion for dynamically allocating stack memory without traversing the input first (`strlen`).